# innerhtml devuelve error indicando que el objeto es nulo en juego javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

hola buenas tardes estoy haciendo una app pequeña de piedra papel o tijera con html y js y esta dividida en dos partes. una parte seria la parte de **el login** y la otra seria **el juego**. El problema es que en mi boton **vsPlayer** que es para elegir jugar contra un jugador al apretarlo e ir a la parte del juego me tendría que reemplazar los carteles en los marcadores con el nombre de los jugadores (mejor dicho del primer jugador porque solo hice ese todavia). Pero el innerhtml me tira esto:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Aqui dejo mis dos documentos html del login y el juego y el js.

```html
<!--Login Part-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css/style.css">
    <title>Rock Paper or Scissors</title>
    
</head>
<body onload="game()">
    <div class="principalContainer" >
        <h1 class="title">Rock Paper or Scissors Game</h1>
        <div class="players">
            <div class="playerOne" id="playerOne"><p class="text-player">Put Your Name Player One</p>
                <input type="text" name="" id="input" placeholder="Put your name here"><i class="plusButton" id="plusButton"><p class="plus">+</p></i>
            </div>
            <div id="oponente" class="oponent">
                <a href="#oponente"><input type="button" id="computer" value=".VS Computer"></a><a href="#playertwo"><input type="button" id="player" value=" .VS Player"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="playertwo" class="playerTwo">
                <p class="text-player-two">Put Your Name Player Two</p>
                <input type="text" name="" id="input-two" placeholder="Put your name here"><i class="plusButton-two" id="plusButton-two"><p class="plus-two">+</p></i>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="playLink">
            <a href="options.html" class="game">Let´s Play Folks!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="seeStats">
            <a href="#stats" class="statsButton">See Stadistics</a>
        </div>
        <div id="stats" class="modal" onload="stadistics()">
            <a href="#"><img src="../img/x-mark.png" alt="exit" class="exit"></a>
            <div class="stats">
                <img src="../img/refresh.png" alt="refresh" class="refresh" id="refresh">
                <p class="statsTitle">Stadistics</p>
                <ul class="gameList" id="gameList">
                    <!--<li>
                        <p class="player">Player1</p>
                        <p class="finalScore">0:3</p>
                        <p class="secondPlayer">Player2</p>
                    </li>-->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../main.js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!--Game Part-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css/gameStyle.css">
    <title>Rock Paper or Scissors</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" onload="game()">
        <div class="playerPoints" id="playerPoints">
            PlayerName
        </div>
        <div class="scoreboard">
            <p class="points" id="points">0:0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="enemyPoints" id="enemyPoints">
            comp/player2
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="turnText" id="turnText">
                Your turn Player 1</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="options">
            <div class="rockContainer">
                <img src="../img/fist.png" alt="rock" class="rock" id="rock">
            </div>
            <div class="paperContainer">
                <img src="../img/hand.png" alt="paper" class="paper" id="paper">
            </div>
            <div class="scissorsContainer">
                <img src="../img/scissors.png" alt="scissors" class="scissors" id="scissors">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="alert">
            <p class="winner" id="winner">Paper cover Rock. You won player one!</p>
        <a href="main.html" class="newGame" id="newGame">Lets go to the menu!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../main.js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
"use strict";


//selecting DOM elements

//login page
const firstInput= document.getElementById("input");
let firstPlusButton= document.getElementById("plusButton");
const compButton= document.getElementById("computer");
const playerButton= document.getElementById("player");
const secondInput= document.getElementById("input-two");
const secondPlusButton= document.getElementById("plusButton-two");

//stadistics DOM elements
const refresh= document.getElementById("refresh");
const playersList= document.getElementById("gameList");

//game DOM elements
const playerName= document.getElementById("playerPoints");
const points= document.getElementById("points");
const enemyName= document.getElementById("enemyPoints");
const turnText= document.getElementById("turnText");
const rock= document.getElementById("rock");
const paper= document.getElementById("paper");
const scissors= document.getElementById("scissors");
const winnerText= document.getElementById("winner");
const menu= document.getElementById("newGame");

let playerOne= {
    name: "",
    option: "",
    points: 0,
}

let playerTwo= {
    name: "",
    option: "",
    points: 0,
}

let computer= {
    name: "Computer",
    option: "",
    points: 0,
}

function game(){
    login();
    versusPlayer();
}

function login(){

    firstPlusButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        playerOne.name= firstInput.value;
        console.log(playerOne.name);
    })
    document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{
        if(event.keyCode===13){
            playerOne.name= firstInput.value;
            console.log(playerOne.name);
        }
    })

    playerButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            
            secondPlusButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
                playerTwo.name= secondInput.value;
                console.log(playerTwo.name);
            })
            document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{
                if(event.keyCode===13){
                    playerTwo.name= secondInput.value;
                    console.log(playerTwo.name);
                }
            })
            
            
            playerName.innerHTML= playerOne.name;
            versusPlayer();
               
        })


    compButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        versusComputer();
        console.log(playerOne.name + " vs computer");
    })
    

     
}

function versusPlayer(){
    console.log("helo")
}
```

Comment: Nunca defines `playerName`. Por supuesto que va a ser null

Comment: si te fijas en la parte donde dice "game DOM elements", la primera linea dsp de eso dice "const playerName" y ahi la puedes ver. Ya intente con todo

Answer (score 4):

Prueba  reemplazando la ultima linea por esto es decir esto:

```
            playerName.innerHTML= playerOne.name;
```

Por esto:

```
        document.getElementById("playerPoints").innerHTML=playerOne.name;
```

Comment: no funciona pero gracias